Understanding the structure of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$.
Let $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ be a root of $x^3 - x + 1$. I am trying to understand the structure of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$.

Does it have a module structure?

Isn't it the case that $\mathbb Z[\alpha] \cong \mathbb Z[x] / (x^3 -
   x + 1)$



In which case isn't $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ a field (since $x^3
   - x + 1$ is irreducible and hence $(x^3 - x +1)$ is a maximal ideal).



Sorry, it’s been a while since I've studied comm algebra so I may be rusty.

Okay, so it’s not a maximal ideal. But I thought in any integral domain an irreducible element generates a maximal ideal?

@azuwaterloo Certainly not, not even in a UFD. Irreducibles generate ideals that are maximal among principal ideals, but not necessarily maximal. E.g., $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but $(x)$ is certainly not maximal.

That ring is NOT a field. Observe that for example $2$ is an element of that ring, but $1/2$ isn't. You may be recalling the result stating that as $x^3-x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, the quotient ring $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-x+1\rangle$ is a field.

We have to show that $\langle f(x)\rangle$ is not a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ when $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial with $\deg(f(x))>1$.
If possible, let $\langle f(x)\rangle$ be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, now consider $\langle p,f(x)\rangle \supsetneq \langle f(x)\rangle$ where $p$ is a prime such that $p$ does not divide the leading coefficient of $f(x)$. It is trivial to see that $\langle p,f(x)\rangle\ne\mathbb Z[x]$, as $\frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{\langle p,f(x) \rangle}\cong\frac{\frac{\mathbb{z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[x]}{\langle f(x) \rangle}\ne 0.$
So, our assumption is wrong. All maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are of the form $\langle p, f(x)\rangle$ where $p$ is a prime integer, and $f$ is a primitive integer polynomial that is irreducible modulo $p$.
Now

If $R$ be a normal domain and $\alpha$ an element of the algebraic closure of the fraction field $K$ of $R$, which is integral over $R$. Then
$R[\alpha] \cong R[x]/\langle f \rangle$, where $f$ is the unique monic minimal
polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, which happens to have coefficients in
$R$.

So your first assumption is correct, but $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is not a field.
To see the structure of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$,first of all look into $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ elements of this ring looks like $a_0 +  a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^{n}$, so elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$  looks like $a_0 +  a_1 \alpha + \cdots + a_n \alpha^{n}$, where $\alpha = x \bmod{f(x)}$.
For example if $\alpha = i = \sqrt{-1}$, then elements of this ring
$\mathbb{Z}[i] $ looks like $a_0 +  a_1 i + \cdots + a_n i^{n} = A + Bi$, where $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $\mathbb{Z}[i] =\{a + i b : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} $.
I hope this will help :)

Ah thanks for that. But then how should one interpret the structure of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$$?

I update the answer.

Use \langle and \rangle for delimiters, not < and >.

Ok, I will keep that in mind. Thanks for this suggestion.

So long,  hey thanks my friend.

It is the case that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-x+1)$. Although $x^3-x+1$ is irreducible, it does not generate a maximal ideal: it does generate a principle ideal, however. It is analogous to the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ for an integer $n$. In this ring, we are basically saying $n\cong 0$. In the case where $n=6$ our ring consists of 0,1,2,3,4, and 5. And when we take $2*4 = 8 =2$. In the case you gave, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-x+1)$, we can now look at it as if $x^3-x+1 \cong 0$, or similarly $x^3\cong x-1$. So in this case, the ring is "spanned" by, $\{0,1,x,x^2\}$. And if we wanted to calculate $x^2*x^2$ we can do that as follows:
$$ x^2 * x^2 = x^4 = x^3*x = (x-1)x = x^2-x $$
If you want to look at $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ it is nearly identical except we now replace $x$ with $\alpha$. However, it is never the case that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a field because all integers, besides -1 and 1, do not a multiplicative inverse. If you wanted this to be a field you could look at $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$.
